# Is Pope's punctuation correct?

Tags: punctuation

There are some famous lines from Alexander Pope's *Eloisa to Abelard* which go:

> How happy is the blameless vestal's lot!
>   The world forgetting, by the world forgot.
>   Eternal sunshine of the spotless mind!
>   Each pray'r accepted, and each wish resign'd?

It seems that a common interpretation of the second line is to read it as:

> [She is] forgetting the world, [and she is] forgotten by the world.

Shouldn't the correct puntuation be:

> The world, forgetting; by the world, forgot.

Is it even Pope's original punctuation that we read today? How can the common punctuation as seen in the first case above be justified?

Comment: If the common interpretation is what Pope intended then his punctuation must be correct - even without popel infalibility

Comment: There are no official punctuation rules, *especially* not in poetry!

Answer (score 1):

No, Pope has it right.  If you go sharpening pencils, then you’ve gone pencils a-sharpening, if you would. Here the vestal’s lot is to be the **world forgetting** — to be forgetting the world.

Pope is placing the object before the verb, using a word order still used in his day, especially in that register.  It is still seen in our neighbor languages but little used in English today. Think of the old-time SOV ordering of:

> And with this ring, I ***thee* wed** (*“I wed you”*)
>
> ...till death ***us* do part**. (*“till death parts us”*)

You would not put a comma after the objects *thee* or *us* there and split them off from their verbs.

With clauses using finite verbs, we don’t use this any longer, but we *do* still use this ordering when we make compound nouns using a gerund and its object:

- apple-bobbing = bobbing for apples
- axe-grinding = grinding axes
- ballot-stuffing = stuffing ballots
- blood-letting = letting (freeing) blood
- cattle-rustling = rustling cattle
- earth-shaking = shaking (the) earth
- life-changing = changing (one’s) life
- man-eating = eating men