# Is the Christmas carol “We Three Kings” intentionally ungrammatical for artistic reasons, or does it use archaic grammar?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, poetry, archaicisms, songs, christmas

I was listening to the “We Three Kings” Christmas carol, and I ended up
taking note of the syntax. Given the use of the *thou/thy/thee/thine*
pronouns for the second-person singular and the vocative particle *O*, it
seems to be using a rather archaic form of English.

Having said that, I’m unfamiliar with some of the syntax, and I wondered
if, as a song, it is quite similar to Shakespeare’s works in that it was,
even at the time of writing, ungrammatical to arrange the words as they
were, but done anyways for aesthetic purposes (in the song’s case, to rhyme
and work with the music).

For punctuation and capitalization, I’ve referenced the [John Henry
Hopkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Henry_Hopkins) collection *Carols, Hymns, and Songs*, using the 1st edition’s
1863 lyrics [from the Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Three_Kings#Lyrics) and the enlarged 2nd edition’s 1872
lyrics [from Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Carols_Hymns_and_Songs_2nd_Ed_enlarged/rmZHyy1WhDsC?gbpv=1&bsq=WE%20THREE%20KINGS%20OF%20ORIENT%20ARE).

> We Three Kings of Orient are,
> Bearing gifts we traverse afar,
> ⁦        Field and fountain,
> ⁦        Moor and mountain,
> Following yonder Star.

*We Three Kings of Orient are* has an SOV arrangement. *Bearing gifts we
traverse afar* seems like it has a punctuation issue — assuming
the *bearing gifts* part is a subordinate clause, there should be a comma
between it and *we traverse afar*. *Following yonder Star* has no subject.

> O Star of Wonder, Star of Night,
> Star with Royal Beauty bright,
> ⁦        Westward Leading,
> ⁦        Still Proceeding,
> Guide us to Thy perfect Light.

I’m guessing that because of the capitalization, *Royal* is not really
considered an adjective in this and is part of a compound noun in *Royal
Beauty*. What confuses me about this is the fact that the adjective
*bright* comes after the noun.

> Born a Kɪɴɢ on Bethlehem plain,
> Gᴏʟᴅ I bring to crown Him again,
> ⁦        King for ever,
> ⁦        Ceasing never,
> Over us all to reign.
>
> ⁦                O Star, &c.

*Gold I bring to crown Him again* has an OSV arrangement. *Over us all to
reign* is an OV arrangement without a subject.

> Fʀᴀɴᴋɪɴᴄᴇɴꜱᴇ to oﬀer have I
> Incense owns a Deity nigh :
> ⁦        Prayer and praising
> ⁦        All men raising,
> Worship Him Gᴏᴅ on High.
>
> ⁦                O Star, &c.

*Frankincense to oﬀer have I* is an OVS arrangement.

> Mʏʀʀʜ is mine ; its bitter perfume
> Breathes a life of gathering gloom ; ⸺  
> ⁦        Sorrowing, sighing,
> ⁦        Bleeding, dying,
> Sealed in the stone-cold tomb.
>
> ⁦                O Star, &c.

I’m confused about the punctuation of the second line — most of
the other lines end in commas or periods (I see it a lot in song lyrics and
poems), but this one ends in a semicolon followed by an em dash. *Sealed in
the stone-cold tomb* does not have a subject.

> Glorious now behold Him arise,
> Kɪɴɢ, and Gᴏᴅ, and Sᴀᴄʀɪꜰɪᴄᴇ  ;
> Heav’n sings Allelujah :
> Allelujah the earth replies.
>
> ⁦                O Star, &c.

*Glorious now behold Him arise* is diﬀicult for me to
analyze — I can’t ﬁgure what is the subject, what is the
object, why *glorious now* is at the beginning, etc.

If I had to guess, I would say that many of “ungrammatical” things I
pointed out are were actually grammatical at one time, but there probably
are some elements that do forgo proper syntax in favour of artistic
expression as well. Still, I would like to know what things were accurate
parts of archaic grammar and how they work.

Comment: Why would you want to analyse this carol? Are you sure you are already proficient at analysing basic constructions?And how do you conclude that "We Three Kings of Orient are" is SOV?

Comment: This is one sentence: *We three kings of Orient are bearing gifts we traverse afar.* *Are bearing* is your verb. *Three kings of Orient* is an appositive for *we*. As in, *We cowboys stick together*, where *cowboys* is an appositive for *we*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Actually, in the bracketed subject NP of "[we three kings of Orient] are bearing..." "we" is a 'personal determinative' functioning as a determiner. Syntactically, it's no different to "[We supporters of Brexit] will triumph".

Comment: @BillJ: That's how your grammar of choice views the matter. Other frameworks view it as apposition.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat No grammarian of any persuasion would analyse [We three kings of Orient are bearing gifts we traverse afar] as  [We three kings of Orient] [are bearing gifts] ... Rather,  [We three kings of Orient are] is a complete main clause in (assuming one calls the necessary locative a 'complement') SCV format. The parody mirrors this ('We three kings of Orient are: one in a taxi, one in a car ...'. And the pattern prevails throughout the carol (with the odd fragment).

Comment: @TinfoilHat In your phrasing of the carol, the only way for "three kings of Orient" to be an appositive NP is if it were a supplementary (non-restrictive) appositive, i.e. separated by a comma, as in We, three kings of Orient ...". But if you accept Edwin's phrasing then "we" is clearly not a determinative and "three kings of Orient" is not an appositive but a complement of the verb "be".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: SCV makes sense now. SVC: _We are three kings of Orient_. SCV: _We three kings of Orient are_. (The locative in the parody— *in a taxi*, etc.—does not apply.) But as a fightin' grammarian, I might argue that the lack of a comma after _bearing gifts_ suggests that _traverse_ is used not in its sense of _travel_ but rather _carry_*: _We kings are bearing gifts that we carry a long way (through fields, etc.), and we are following yonder star._ *OED: †23. To move or carry in a trailing manner; to trail, drag. Obsolete. Only attested in the form _travish_. **OK, it's a stretch.**

Comment: @BillJ: Maybe CGEL requires the NP after *we* to be nonrestrictive (as in: *we, three kings of Orient,*) to qualify as an appositive, but other frameworks do not.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat But lyrics and poetry are not governed by the same punctuation conventions as standard running text. // I normally DV questions involving such non-standard conventions, but feel there is enough valuable discussion in this thread not to.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Right, hence the varied interpretations. That was how I got from *We three kings of Orient are (,) Bearing gifts we traverse afar* to *We three kings of Orient are bearing gifts we traverse afar* —by ignoring that comma. Now that I read this yet again, I would actually parse it like this: *We three kings of Orient are bearing gifts (.) We traverse afar (through field and fountain, moor and mountain), following yonder star.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Pray ponder whether reading dim [yesteryear’s haphazard commas](http://www.laits.utexas.edu/poltheory/james/blaste/blaste.html) neath aftermorrow’s unsparing beam mightn’t unawares impute more purpose behind those antique motes, or their absency, than would, under the ministrations of the well-whetted blade of the Barber of Ockham, belike obtain.  

Comment: @TinfoilHat What "other frameworks" are you referring to? Ones that you read about on the back of a breakfast cereal packet?

Comment: @BillJ: Yes, those. Starting at page 76 of 
[The Grammars of Close Apposition](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/294105289_The_Grammars_of_Close_Apposition), there's an analysis of "close appositives" in the structure of *We Xs*. In the introduction, the author notes: *"...no one-size-fits-all approach to the grammar of the noun phrase can capture the complexity of the general category of close apposition..., since it is characterized by both a unique mixture of idiosyncratic conventionalization and large pockets of idiomaticity."* Back to breakfast.

Comment: @BillJ I never said I was proficient in it at all—I'm not sure why you would I assume that I would be. I'm trying to learn to be proficient, which it seems I am a good ways off from. That's why I decided to pull this carol apart and ask this question—so that I could fill in gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: @TinfoilHat In order for the NP to be in integrated apposition, the noun it modifies (the 'head') would have to be a pronoun since NPs don’t normally modify determiners. But the construction is restricted to 1st and 2nd person plurals only, i.e. we can't say, for example *"they supporters of Brexit will prevail" or *”I supporter of a federal Europe …”. This demonstrates that the head cannot be a pronoun; it can only be a determiner.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Further, the personal determinatives “we” and “you” are exactly parallel to other definite determiners such as the demonstratives in permitting the universal quantifier “all” as a predeterminer, as in “all we/those supporters of a federal Europe.” This property distinguishes them from the personal pronouns, which permit “all” only when postmodified: “All we/you who support a federal Europe will win the argument”, but not *”All you/we will win the argument”. This too shows that the appositive analysis is incorrect.

Comment: @BillJ: The point is that analyses vary. After exploring a number of them, the author concludes: *"...we can always stipulate ways (rules) out of the problem, but the fact remains that these constructions only admit first and second person plural personal pronouns and the accusative third person plural, and that that extreme form of choosiness is incompatible with both the determiner view and the [close appositive] view, or with any other rule system we might be inclined to contemplate. The construction must be learned and stored..."*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Analyses should be based on evidence. I supplied adequate evidence to support the claim that "we" and "you" cannot be pronouns (which they would need to be for the appositive analysis.to work) and hence they must be determinatives. My second comment - concerning the universal quantifier "all" - is perhaps the more convincing one.

Comment: @thepufferfish I hope you're following all this!

Answer (score 10):

No, it isn’t being ungrammatical, deliberately or otherwise.

- It uses some old-style or poetic ordering at times for the sake of the meter (*metri causa*) or of the rhyme (*rimae causa*), but neither [OSV nor CSV](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/267150/2085) is *especially* exotic, let alone [SOV](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/360156/2085) or SCV.
- It is effecting a style from Early Modern English or even Middle English
  that was no longer current as of the mid 1800s when it was written, but was still remembered.

---

## Historical Background

Christmas saw hard times under Oliver Cromwell’s Interregnum, when churches weren’t even permitted to be open on Christmas Day unless it happened to fall on a Sunday. Remember that Cromwell was a Puritan, and Puritans didn’t like the secular observations of Christmas, particularly their pre-Christian elements and their mercantile connections.

So before all memory of Christmases past was forever lost, during the later 1700s through the early 1800s hurried folklorists researched, assembled, and published as many existing Christmas carols as they could find still passed down by living memory in the oral tradition of the English countryside.

In 1822, Davies Gilbert published *A Collection of Ancient Christmas
Carols, with the tunes to which they were formerly sung in the West of
England* which contained some of these old forms. In his preface, he wrote:

> The Editor is desirous of preserving them in their actual forms, however
> distorted by false grammar or by obscurities, as specimens of times now
> passed away, and of religious feelings superseded by others of a different
> cast. He is anxious also to preserve them on account of the delight they
> afforded him in his childhood; when the festivities of Christmas Eve were
> anticipated by many days of preparation, and prolonged through several
> weeks by repetitions and remembrances.

The version of “God Rest You Merry Gentlemen” that William Sandys included
in his *Christmas Carols, Ancient and Modern; Including the Most Popular in
the West of England, and the Airs to Which They Are Sung* of 1833 was
notably more archaic in syntax than the version of that song that had been
published little more than fifty years earlier in 1775. Many objects, complements,
and adjuncts that had previously come after the verb as you would normally
expect were moved up so they fell before the verb instead.

Starting with the treasures unearthed by the folklorists, the Victorians
set about creating an “old-time” popular conception of Christmas.  Others
who deliberately used older language constructions during the 19th century
include Walter Scott, Charles Dickens, and Washington Irving.

Many new songs were composed during this time with archaic language for the effect of sounding ancient. For example, in 1853,
John Mason Neale devised
somewhat archaic lyrics for his “Good King Wenceslas”, setting it to
the tune of an old Latin song schoolboys of that time would have been
familiar with from their Latin classes, and both words and music were
included in that year’s *Carols for Christmas-tide* collection.

So it was in **this** prevailing environment that John Henry Hopkins in 1857
wrote his “Three Kings of Orient”.  In doing so, he deliberately chose these older syntactic patterns of English from earlier centuries.  This practice merely
reflects what so many other writers were similarly doing during those decades.

---

## Modern Confusions

You’re missing a lot of subjects of things that are actually there. Those many verb phrases with present or past participle forms do refer to some noun phrase you aren't seeing; they are not orphaned absolutes.

Yes, there's some use of appositives, but a lot of the mystery may be because you aren’t used to seeing a verb’s objects, complements, and adverbial adjuncts  preceding their verbs instead of following them. But [precede them they do](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78595/2085), and often.

You shouldn’t read too much into the old-style punctuation like the French-style punctuation-spacing or how they sometimes liked [an especially long dash after a colon or semicolon](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/409522/2085) to indicate greater pause. Neither should you put too much trust in gleaning some special purpose behind the *D*eliberate *U*se of Mᴇᴀɴɪɴɢꜰᴜʟ Cᴀᴘɪᴛᴀʟɪᴢᴀᴛɪᴏɴ that it was ﬁrst printed with.

### A Loose Paraphrasal

Completely oﬀ the cuﬀ, but why don’t you try reading it more like this:

> We are three kings who have come with presents from the Orient. We  have crossed diverse and distant lands following that one star way over there.
>
> Guide us to your perfect light, O star of wonder, O star of night, O star that is bright with royal beauty and is leading west and is still going.
>
> I bring gold to re-crown a king who was born on the plains of Bethlehem, a king who will never cease reigning over us forever.
>
> I have the ﬁnest incense to oﬀer its rightful owner, a nearby deity, one all men are sending prayers of praise: “Worship him God on high!”
>
> My gift is myrrh, whose bitter fragrance brings to mind a future darkness of sorrowing and sighing and bleeding and dying and getting locked away in a stone-cold tomb.
>
> Now see him arise in glory: king and God and sacriﬁce. Heaven sings “Hallelujah” and Earth replies “Hallelujah”.

See if that pedestrian paraphrasing can help you understand the original.

Basically, wherever something looks missing or out of order in the original, all you have to make sense of it is to drag parts of it around till they ﬁt together the way you’re expecting them to. :)

### Poetic Devices

The ordering of syntactic constituents is notoriously flexible in poetry, owing in part to poetic devices like ***hyperbaton*** and ***anastrophe*** to [bring the important word to the fore](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78595/2085) by rearranging the typical order.

- See for example Longfellow’s *“This is the **forest primeval**...”* from the opening line of *Evangeline*.
- Also see Virgil’s *“**Arma virumque** cano...”* (Latin for “Of arms and of men I sing”) from the epic opening of the *Aeneid*, which the poet wrote for [Caesar Augustus](https://www.hymnsandcarolsofchristmas.com/Hymns_and_Carols/augustus_caesar_having_brought1.htm) himself, who just happened to be reigning over the Levant during the storied time of your Christmas carol’s setting.

Comment: Good answer. On the other hand, the corrupted version that kids used to sing in the schoolyards of Corpus Christi, Texas, in the early 1960s really was ungrammatical—at least in the crossover from the first line to the second: "We three kings of Orient are / Tried to light a rubber cigar / It was loaded and it exploded / Blowing us all afar." As a first-grader, I thought that the three kings were claiming to be from a place called "Arientar," which would have solved the syntactical problem.

Comment: @Sven I'm sure (rare) that the first line is a complete independent clause, SCV (the complement or whatever being here the prepositional phrase).

Comment: @SvenYargs At my elementary school, "Blowing us all afar" was replaced with a sudden silence, followed by "We two kings of Orient are."

Answer (score 2):

> We Three Kings of Orient are, Bearing gifts we traverse afar, Field
> and fountain, Moor and mountain, Following yonder Star.

We are three kings of the orient (We are three oriental kings),

We travel long distances carrying gifts,

(We pass via) fields and fountains, moors and mountains,

Following that star over there.

> What confuses me about this is the fact that the adjective "bright"
> comes after the noun.

It comes at the end of the line in order to rhyme with "Light" and "night".

Poems and song lyrics are not required to follow the normal rules.

Comment: It is a star that is ***bright with*** royal beauty.

Answer (score 0):

It's what my dad (facetiously) called 'poetic licence' when I caught him out in a grammatical error. Chambers Dictionary defines it as 'an allowable departure…for the sake of effect, as frequently occurs in poetry'. The key word is 'allowable'.

Comment: Poetic license does apply, but this would benefit from more of an explanation in context.  Welcome to EL&U; please take a moment to [tour] the site and read the [FAQ].  Your [edit]s are encouraged.

Comment: Being written in 1857, the hymn was doubtless subject to different 'rules' and style preferences, so 'error' is possibly unwarranted. ' ... which art in Heaven' would sound very dubious to some nowadays.